# Python Lists "list index out of range" error when trying to find value 1 of a list 6 long

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to code a program that will accept a list as an input. The first number should be a specified range. The last number should be a maximum value. Then, within the specified range, excluding the first value, output all numbers less than or equal to the maximum value. The code is here:

```
nums = input().splitlines()

theRange = int(nums[0])
highNum = int(nums[-1])

i = 1
while (i <= theRange) and (i <= len(nums)):
    if int(nums[i]) <= theRange:
        print(nums[i])
    i += 1
```

After inputting:

```
5
50
60
140
200
75
100
```

The error that results is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    if int(nums[i]) <= theRange:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This makes no sense as the *theRange* variable is less than the length of *nums*.
Please tell me why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Print `i` as the first statement in the while loop. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you are using an IDE now would be a good time to familiarize yourself with its debug features. [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) in the standard library can also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists in Python are zero-based, so you should use the `<` operator, not `<=`:

```py
while (i < theRange) and (i < len(nums)):
```

Comment: Thanks. I realy need to remember that Java and Python are similar in how they handle arrays.